# How do I update a GitHub forked repository to a specific branch/tag?

Tags: git, github

I want to upgrade a forked repo which I forked 1 year ago to a specific tag. Anyone know how to do this ?

Answer (score 5):

If you did not already do that:

- Clone the forked repository on your machine.
- Add an `upstream` remote to the original repository (`git remote add upstream <url>`)

Then:

- `git fetch upstream --tags`
- `git checkout -b <branchname> <tagname>`

After that, you will have a new branch named *branchname* which is at the same state as the tag. Finally,

- `git push origin <branchname>`

pushes the new branch to your GitHub fork of the repository.

(I assume this is what you want; if you just want to have the tags in your fork, use `git push origin --tags`)

Comment: Thanks. But I solved my problem using this command:
`git rebase --onto tags/<tag_name> upstream/master master`

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by following these steps:

- `git checkout master`
- `git remote add upstream <origianl_repo_link>`
- `git fetch upstream`
- `git rebase --onto tags/<tag_name> upstream/master master`